# Make a Celery task that waits for a signal?

Tags: celery

Is it possible to create Celery task that just waits for a signal? I have this scenario:

- Scrapyd in one virtualenv on remote machine A
- Django project with Celery worker node in another virtualenv on remote machine A
- The same Django project with Celery, but in another virtualenv on local machine B

How I use this setup:

1. I would send a task chain from Django on machine B
2. Let the task chain be consumed by the worker node on machine A.
3. In the first subtask of the task chain, I would schedule a crawl using Scrapyd's JSON over HTTP API, and pass the Celery task ID to the crawler as an HTTP request parameter.
4. I then want this first subtask to just wait for some kind of signal.
5. Scrapyd does its thing and runs the spider.
6. Once the spider is done crawling, I want it to send a signal, maybe by JSON over HTTP or by a Django management command, to the subtask that has been waiting for the signal.

Is this doable?

I would just need code snippets to show me how to wait for a signal in a subtask, and how to restore a task from the task ID and send a signal to it.

Comment: Waiting for something in worker is really bad idea. Try rearranging the logic forking a subprocess which handles long operations and then queues another task to complete the operation.

Comment: Break this process in 3 tasks.